# Bootstrap 4 my col won't go in line in mobile device

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm currently trying to use Bootstrap 4 and I need your help,
I want to create a 2 columns grid with a row and when it became to mobile device the second column go to line :

So I'm doing this :

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <img src="my source" alt="My alt" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <h2>My title</h2>
                    <p>My text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Which was working on Bootstrap 3 but it doesn't work in V4.

I want something like this :

```css
.row>div{
  width: 49.7%;
  display: inline-block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 991px){
  .row>div{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="first_column">My first column</div>
  <div id="second_column">My second column</div>
</div>
```

How can I make it ? Thanks for helping me,

Comment: Please read the Bootstrap docs. col- should always be the immediate child of row.. so you can't have cols directly in other cols.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You had it almost right. I have removed this div:

```
<div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">
```

So I think that this is the code you're looking for:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <img src="my source" alt="My alt" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <h2>My title</h2>
      <p>My text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

This works fine with Bootstrap 4.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/5d2n72r4/

Comment: @KévinHuang No problem!